# verify div with is-disabled by screen from test-library

Tags: javascript, typescript, unit-testing, testing

I try to use screen from test-library on unit test for my component and how can I verify the button is disabled based on the jsx generated from component? I have tried to use `toBeDisabled` but get the error `Received element is not disabled:`
ref: https://kentcdodds.com/blog/common-mistakes-with-react-testing-library

```
// test.ts
const button = screen.getByText('I am action Button')
expect(button.closest('div')).toBeDisabled();

// screen.debug()
<body>
  <div>
    <div class="menu is-disabled">
      <a class="bar-button">
        <span class="bar-label">
          I am action Button
        </span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Is it changing to disabled? If so, may be worth wrapping in a `waitFor`: `await waitFor(() => { expect(button.closest('div')).toBeDisabled() })`

Comment: I can see the class on div included `menu is-disabled`

Answer (score 1):

[toBeDisabled](https://github.com/testing-library/jest-dom#tobedisabled) is only applicable for specific elements and `div` is not one of them. Based on what you have, you can use [toHaveClass](https://github.com/testing-library/jest-dom#tohaveclass),

```
expect(button.closest('div')).toHaveClass('is-disabled');
```

Comment: hm..i have the error `TS2339: Property 'toHaveClass' does not exist on type 'HTMLDivElement'.`

Comment: Can you confirm if you have the `@testing-library/jest-dom` package in your application? I think this is a types issue and typescript is telling it cannot find the definition of this method, which tells us that some types are missing. Do you see `toHaveClass` show up correctly in the code and are able to see the definition of it?